# How to implement a resilient bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring bean that access an external system through http in its constructor.
If the external system is not available at startup the bean cannot be created and application fails to start properly.

I want my application to be able to start regardless of extenal systems. I would rather have missing functionality for a while than having to restart the application.

I know this should be achievable in Spring with the right choice of scope and a proxying bean factory but I'm not sure how actually do it. It seems to me that most parts of Spring AOP is aimed at modifying targets that are succesfully created and is not able to handle excpetions during creation or am I wrong?

In short: I want a proxy that creates the target bean at first access and then retains that instance as long as it works. If it fails to create it, it should throw an exception and retry next time the proxy is called.

So, how would you implement this functionality?

Comment: I wouldn't say Spring is really going to be much help for you here. It would likely be easier to implement the resilience yourself, using simple exception handling and state control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a ResilientBeanProxy that defer the actual creation to later, so yes, it is almost as Spring's lazy init but with the added feature that it handles exceptions during init. e.g. it will not halt the creation of the application context an error occurs during startup.

If the creation fails, it will be retried at the next invocation.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that code is long lost in the haze of history.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried lazy bean initiation?

```
<bean id="lazy" class="com.foo.ExpensiveToCreateBean" lazy-init="true"/>
```

you should not set this bean as property to Singleton bean because it will initiate it on startup.

Comment: lazy won't do it because the component is used by other singletons so it will be created at startup anyway

Answer (score 0):

Consider if Your bean really depends on remote resource in construction time? Maybe You could  simply use **lazy init** here? You wouldn't call this external system in constructor, but on first call to it's method when the remote resource is needed. Than if the resource is not there, thow a kind of `ResourceUnavailableException` with a message `'Try again later'`.

Comment: There's some stuff that need to happen in construction time, if I defer that to later, there will be messy state checking code all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, but I was just trying to follow a similar pattern and in my scenario Lazy init worked.

As long as both the bean **and** injection point (`@Autowire` or constructor parameter) are marked as `@Lazy` then the bean wont be created until first accessed.

If the bean creation fails (throws an Exception), the Component accessing the bean can handle the exception. However, as no instance of the bean is added to the context (because creation failed), the next access of the bean will try to create it again.

This seems to work fine in my context, where the bean is a connection to a remote webservice, the WSDL of which might not be available at startup.