# Remove Cassandra connectivity as hard Spring startup dependency

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, datastax, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring Data with Cassandra and would like to be as resilient as possible in terms of error prevention and handling. Currently, we wrap our our `com.datastax.cassandra.Session` by implementing the interface with our own implementation that creates a nested instance (effectively a proxy), like so:

```
private class CassandraSessionProxy implements Session {
    private Session cassandraSession;
    private Session cassandraSession() {
        if (cassandraSession != null) {
            return cassandraSession;
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    cassandraSession = createCassandraSession();
                    return cassandraSession;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("An error happened but after Spring's container started", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // implement Session methods, proxying to cassandraSession field
    @Override
    public void close() {
        cassandraSession().close();
    }
}
```

All proxying methods in our Session implementation access the cassandraSession field through a synchronized block that checks if it exists and if not creates the connection, catching any exceptions outside of the scope of Spring's startup.

Curious if there is a slicker method for achieving this. An overlooked feature of datastax's native driver or spring-data would be ideal.

Much obliged :)

Comment: See also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468249/graceful-handling-of-exception-thrown-while-creating-beans

Comment: Unlike that scenario, the exception is temporal and I want the app to still startup and operate normally when Cassandra is back online

Answer (score 1):

Session is an interface. Why don't you simply construct a SessionBuilder that constructs a Session instance? You can then have it return a basic Cassandra Session until you need something else.

The above solution is usually best practice when it comes to OO design.

Comment: The Cassandra Session is throwing the error that stops Spring startup.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using synchronisation correctly. Your check for null is not a part of any happens-before flow so results are not guaranteed.

I would use static holder instead, or even do not use lazy initialisation at all.